# How to check video, AB test, on different screens: balancing colors, etc

Tags: after-effects, filter, color-correction

Is there a standard way of checking a render as it would be seen on different screens (iPads, monitors, tvs, whatever) for colors etc.. 
Maybe AB/Testing software? (Wanted to add the tag ab-testing, but my rep isn't high enough yet)

As a reference I have a song & corresponding music video (see link below).
I'm wondering if I affected (washed out) the colors too much. I'd like to know the differences on different screens. How can you effectively check on different screens (on your own pc). Reference:

Thanks,
Yves

Comment: Yves - when making your own videos you can do whatever you want with them. Posting here to ask our opinion on your video is a bit odd and feels off topic. If your question is **How can I check my video on different screens?** then that may be on topic, but doesn't need the video included in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion? I thought I'd provide an example. My apologies if that felt differently. I do however want to know "How can I check my video on different screens?" / "How can I do AB testing on my own screen".. Is there a tool? I'll try to edit the post.

I edited the post now - I hope this is a better format of posting in the AVP stackexchange site. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Yves - that works much better. The focus is now on your question - the previous one just felt a bit like spam. I see that wasn't intended now, so have upvoted.

Comment: No prob, thanks for pointing it out. I should've put more attention to formulating this question. On stackofverflow this is easier, but with creative questions - it's sometimes a bit more difficult. Anyway, let's hope some answers come on. Thx again :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to deal with this is to use color calibration.  Unfortunately, color accuracy on consumer devices tends to be all over the charts.  There is no way to guarantee that the color will be similar, even on multiple of the same model of device, or even on the same exact device over time.

Thus, the best practice is to setup a color calibrated environment that you can verify the content looks correct in.  You can then run your encodings for different profiles and compare them in an environment where you know the differences will show up clearly.  The results on end user devices may vary based on how good their screens actually are, but building to a standard high quality, calibrated display should produce the best overall outcome across devices.

If you want to get really advanced, you can also generate or obtain ICC profiles of the average for the device screen you want to display the video on.  This profile can then be applied to the video on a calibrated display to alter the colors to be similar to that produced by the device.  It still won't take in to account pixel density though.  If you want to know exactly what it will look like on a display, there is no substitute for actually sending it to that display since pixel layout and density, as well as the surface type and size, make a gigantic difference in the way the video looks.

Using the device itself is also helpful for ensuring that the video can decode and play smoothly within the constraints of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike print graphics there is no way of really controlling the colour in video as seen by the final user, unless you know the profiles of all the devices it will be played on. The best you can do is that your material is properly exposed and balanced to give it the best chance out there in the cruel world.

Using scopes is the objective way to test your material. Waveform monitors, histograms and vector scopes give you information about levels, colour and balance that is independent of the playback device, but you've got to know how to read them.

Here's a good [vectorscopes 101 tutorial](http://www.glennchan.info/articles/technical/vectorscopes.html) from Glenn Chann and a [How to](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/premierepro/cs/using/WSCE1EF46C-AB40-45f9-BAD8-D790421BD01A.html) for Premiere (but can be extrapolated for any software)